# Sharing Rendering Surfaces (FrameBuffers, Pbuffers, etc.) between OpenGL ES 2 Applications/Processes

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, embedded-linux

I'm currently designing some OpenGL ES 2.0-enabled applications on an ARM-based, Embedded Linux system using C++ and I want to share the rendering surface (FBO or RenderBuffer generated by OpenGLES2 or Pbuffer created by EGL) of an app "A" with another app "B".

Since I'm a beginner with OpenGL ES 2 *(and, more importantly, since the buffers are on the GPU's memory over which I have no control nor access)*, I first thought of mapping a shared memory object (e.g. an `uint8_t` array of length `width*height*colorComponentCount`, using POSIX `shm_open()` etc.) between the two processes and periodically calling `glReadPixels()` on app "A" for filling it then uploading it in app "B" as, for instance, a 2D texture. Of course, a shared synchronization mechanism, such as a named semaphore, is to be used as well, but that is not the point of my question:

I am aware that downloading a buffer from the GPU (i.e. `glReadPixels()` in app "A") and then uploading it back (i.e. texture 2D in app "B") is not the *optimal* solution for sharing rendering surfaces between OpenGL ES applications, that is why I would like to know if there is better solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The glReadPixels() approach is the only way to do it in a portable, platform independent way for OpenGL ES 2.0 and it is incredibly slow.  Pixmaps allocated by the EGL (not pbuffers) would be good if any platform actually implemented them.

I recommend either:

Implement the apps so that they share a common instance of OpenGL ES somehow and use FBOs with texture attachments to share the images.  If you need portability.

Or, you could customize your linux platform to provide support for this either at the kernel level or with a customized EGL that implements Pixmap support.  These articles will help with FBOs and the EGL Image extension:

```
http://montgomery1.com/opengl/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

As you might have guessed, I do actually prefer platform independence/portability (at this point, patching the Linux platform is not an option). Also, the programs/processes need to be _independent_ (except for the shared rendering surface or, in general, the mechanism used for passing one app's rendering result to the other)

Comment: I did have a look at [TI's wiki](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES) but I haven't found sample code for manipulating Pixmaps, I am still searching (I don't know whether the platform I'm using implements them, I should probably code a test program to check it). It is a shame that the [OpenGL ES 2 Programming Guide](http://opengles-book.com/) does not cover a topic such as sharing rendering surfaces between processes...

Comment: Yes it is a shame.  Pixmaps were intended to be the solution to this problem but I have never seen a platform that actually implements them in a usable form except maybe iOS and Android has their own GraphicBuffer.

Comment: Sharing rendering surfaces through shared memory is really unefficient... Is there any way of directly addressing the buffer on the GPU ?

Comment: It depends on the platform. Android and iOS have it and some embedded linux platforms (Freescale) have implemented the EGL Image Extension.